# DataError 'invalid syntax for type timestamp' - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to load, all `sale.order` objects on draft state, and also trying to filter all these drafts by dates, so far, this is what I have:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('sale_order')
def _compute_amount_total(self):
    draft_orders = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft'),('date_order','<=', time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')),('date_order','>=',time.strftime('%%Y-09-01'))])  
    amount_total = sum(draft_orders.mapped('amount_total'))
    for record in self:
        record.amount_total = amount_total
```

But when I try to access this on my view, this is the error i get:

```
2017-08-26 23:34:35,292 4868 ERROR bsi_def openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5955, in onchange
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5657, in __getitem__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 838, in __get__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 946, in determine_draft_value
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 885, in _compute_value
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\account_budget_extended\models\models.py", line 170, in _compute_amount_total
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 1650, in search
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4708, in _search
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 171, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 247, in execute
DataError: la sintaxis de entrada no es vÃƒÂ¡lida para tipo timestamp: Ã‚Â«%Y-12-31Ã‚Â»
LINE 1: ...e" = 'draft')  AND  ("sale_order"."date_order" <= '%Y-12-31'...
```

I think is Postgres related, but I'm not sure how to declare a domain filter of date type on Odoo's orm.

The draft domain works perfectly, I think the domain concatenation is also fine, there must be something with the date domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think here is a problem:`time.strftime('%%Y-12-31')` and `time.strftime('%%Y-09-01')`, it should be with a single `%` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubling the percent sign escapes it. If you want to use it as part of a format specifier then you must only have one.

Comment: LOL, Thank You very much